# socket io with ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, socket.io

I'm just getting started with Socket.IO and can't wrap my head around what seems to be a pretty basic idea.

I have a server:

**app.js**

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    });
});
```

How can I send a 'news' event to the server through a simple Ruby script?  Something like this:

**socket.rb**

```
require 'socket'
socket = TCPSocket.new('localhost', 8080)
socket.send('news: some message', 0)
```

I'm not sure how to pass the news data, and I'm probably doing something else wrong as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that WebSockets have a very specific protocol. You'll either need to implement all of the protocol yourself or use a WebSocket client library. There are several around for Ruby, though I haven't tried them and thus wouldn't feel comfortable recommending one — just Google "Ruby websocket client" and you can have your pick.